# Some simple questions about geolocation (GPS) values from Android

Tags: android, geolocation

The long/lat coords format that I seem to get back from Android (Phonegap) are decimal.

May I know what are the ranges of both the longitude and latitude values?

Also, how can I find distance between 2 points in the decimal format? Thanks!

Comment: I think [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/587047/virtualearth-determine-min-max-visible-latitude-longitude) is your answer. In what units you want to have distance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latitude and longitude are specified in millionths of a degree: divide each value by 1000000 (and convert to float or double) to get the true degrees.

Similar question:

[Android GeoPoint with lat/long values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577866)

Answer (score 1):

For calculating distance between 2 points, have a look at the haversine formula. A javascript-implementation that can be used with phonegap is described here: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html